# Is it possible to recover unflushed data from the disk/page cache?

Tags: kernel, usb, cache, data-recovery

In Ubuntu, I move some file to a USB stick, using `mv dir/file /media/7EXXX/swap/`. When finishing this, I forget to "safely remove" before physically removing usb stick. Now, the `file` is not shown in usb. Is it possible to retrieve data not yet written to USB (which I assume resides on page/disk cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "No, sorry, but your data's gone" :(

Shutdown as soon as possible (maybe even uncleanly) and use a LiveCD, etc. to mount your source partition and recover the file with `testdisk`/`photorec`, etc.

Remember to append a `; sync` next time so you know the file has been written to the USB when the prompt reappears.

---

In general it's almost impossible to retrieve data from the file cache unless you can somehow find what the "page cache" process is, and then there would be other issues.

You can examine and dump the contents of a process's memory from `/proc/$pid/mem` with a debugger such as `gdb` -- but the process must be able to be SIGSTOPped. So: the requirements to dump the file cache to a disk file for analysis and possible recovery with `testdisk`, `photorec`, etc. are something like:

- Find the elusive "page cache" process
- Make sure it's stoppable
- Dump its memory to disk
- All without rebooting

Someone who has significant experience with kernel development could probably put together some code to do this...

Comment: There is no page cache process.

Comment: Hence *elusive*, and the quotes around that page cache ;)